# Flickering Parts

Tags: mesh

I have a clock mesh(picture1) and when i move my camera, horizantal and vertical numbers (especially the III) flicker but ones with degrees. And when i zoom out, the III fades out way before others (as in picture 2). What causes it ? How can it be fixed ?

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there is any overlapping face between your objects? Could you tell a bit more about your scene setup/objectìs rig? Are you using drivers?

Comment: There is no overlapping faces, i controlled it. I am new at Blender so i am still learning. I don't know how to check how rigid mesh is. I use this scene (https://prnt.sc/gamr1x) to bake textures. I uploaded my mesh to a game. Then it was as i told above. Then i checked my mesh in Blender so it was same. Then i decided it has something to do with my mesh. Sorry what drivers ?

Comment: With "rig" I meant to ask you if something has been "rigged" for animations. Drivers are properties that control other properties, but as you don't konw what they are, I may guess you didn't used them. I'll suggest you to upload your file, or a portion of it, to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can have a wider look at all the parameters of the object.

Comment: i added the file.

Comment: Thanks for the file. I'm sorry but I can't see any fickering. I can zoom In and out while seeing all the numbers. All works fine in my PC. Could you record a video?

Comment: Sorry for bad quality. If you look at the gif, when i zoom out, all numbers stay same but III. It causes flickring with texture on. https://gyazo.com/ecd175d8d41518b7330c62cceba5f9a1

Comment: I think that is a case of a very thin part of the mesh aligning with pixels on the screen. That is as the "line" aligns to the edge of a pixel, sometimes it is drawn in the pixel and sometimes the background gets drawn.

Comment: Then, there is nothing i can do about it ?

Comment: you can slightly rotate or move up the model, and see if it still it happens. Also plz post the blend file for study if possible!